# Returning property and count columns together in Neo4jClient Cypher Query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4jclient

I have a Cypher query likes this:

```
START n=node:permit_idx(PmtID= "111")
Match n-[:Assinged]->m<-[:Assinged]-p
RETURN p.PmtID, count(m);
```

I got error when I try to do it using Neo4jClient Cypher Query

```
 var results = graphClient
                 .Cypher
                 .Start(new { n = Node.ByIndexLookup("permit_idx", "PmtID", "111") })
                 .Match("Match n-[:Assigned]->m<-[:Assigned]-p")
                 .Return((m, p) => new
                                    {
                                        PDPmtID = "p.PmtID",
                                        MCount = "count(m)"
                                    })
                 .Results;
```

If only need to return one property or one count, we can use

```
.Return<int>("count(m)");
```

But how to return property and count together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.Return((m, p) => new
{
    PDPmtID = Return.As<int>("p.PmtID"),
    MCount = m.Count()
})
```

Or, preferred right now:

```
.Return((m, p) => new
{
    Permit = p.As<Permit>(),
    MCount = m.Count()
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the custom text option in your compound Return clause:

```
.Return((m, p) => new
{
    PDPmtID = Return.As<int>("p.PmtID"),
    MCount = Return.As<int>("count(m)")
})
```

(This is based on the documentation for the [Neo4jClient](http://hg.readify.net/neo4jclient/wiki/cypher))